# Generic Term for Warnings and Errors?

Tags: naming

Consider you want to insert Errors and Warnings into the same database entity. How would you call the table?

Example:

```
+----+-------+---------+
| ID | TYPE  | MESSAGE |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | ERROR |   FOO   |
|  2 | WARNG |   BAR   |
|  3 | ERROR |   TXT   |
+----+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collegue thinks `Signal` would be the generic term from a process point of view.

Answer (score 1):

`Message` would be my best personal guess, but English is not my mother tounge.

Answer (score 1):

I would use **Anomaly**. It is also a nice Matrix reference, so some users may chuckle. :)